# Editable Content - focus and click problems

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I have an editable content div, that a user adds elements to. The user has a side menu with all the available tags that can be added by click on each tag. It is also possible to type in text before/after each tag.

Each tag element has `contenteditable="false"`, for example:

```css
.keyword-item {
  background-color: #EEFDE5;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: unset;
  cursor: pointer; 
  margin: 0 0.25rem 0 0.25rem;
}

img {
  padding-left: 2%;
}

span {
  padding-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="expression-textarea">
  <label class="keyword-item" contenteditable="false">
    <input type="hidden" value="1">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/small/16/000000/download-2.png"/>
        <span>bla</span>
    </label>
  <label class="keyword-item" contenteditable="false">
    <input type="hidden" value="2">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/small/16/000000/download-2.png"/>
        <span>bla bla 2</span>
    </label>
  <label class="keyword-item" contenteditable="false">
        <input type="hidden" value="18">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/small/16/000000/download-2.png"/>
        <span>bla2</span>
     </label>
</div>
```

Two problems with this (with Chrome at least):

1. When I'm using the keyboard arrows to navigate around those items, it works well. However, mouse navigation is a little bizzare; It seems impossible to get the cursor between the second and the third icon.
2. The first item is being deleted only by focusing in front of it and pressing the `DEL` key, it doesn't delete by focusing after it and pressing backspace.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish what you're looking for using [flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp):

```css
#expression-textarea {
  padding-left: 2px;
  display: flex;
}

.keyword-item {
  background-color: #EEFDE5;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: unset;
  cursor: pointer; 
  margin: 0 0.25rem 0 0.25rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

img {
  padding-left: 2%;
}

span {
  padding-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="expression-textarea">
  <span></span>
  <div class="keyword-item" contenteditable="false">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/small/16/000000/download-2.png"/>
    bla
  </div>
  <span></span>
  <div class="keyword-item" contenteditable="false">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/small/16/000000/download-2.png"/>
      bla bla 2
  </div>
  <span></span>
  <div class="keyword-item" contenteditable="false">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/small/16/000000/download-2.png"/>
    bla2
  </div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

I did also modify some of the markup - removing the `input`s, using `div`s instead of `label`s, etc.

Using the above code, navigating with the arrows as well as with the mouse works as you'd expect.

The padding on the left side wrapper `div` is so that you can see the cursor at the start of the `div`.

Comment: Thanks patrick, it works wonderfully from UI/UX prespective - I must however have the hidden `input` to interpret the value of the tag (id, fetched from server). Any suggenstions?

Comment: Could you use a custom attribute? Something like “data-*=“ ? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp You should also be able to make the hidden input work, I just removed it for simpler markup.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm looking into that.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a button instead of a label/input? It seems to fix the mouse selection issues.
Adding an empty tag at the beginning of the contenteditable div allows the first tag to be deleted.

```css
.keyword-item {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font: inherit;
  background-color: #EEFDE5;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  margin: 0 .25rem;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="expression-textarea">
  <span></span>
  <button class="keyword-item" contenteditable="false">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/small/16/000000/download-2.png"/>
    <span>bla</span>
  </button>
  <button class="keyword-item" contenteditable="false">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/small/16/000000/download-2.png"/>
    <span>bla bla 2</span>
  </button>
  <button class="keyword-item" contenteditable="false">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/small/16/000000/download-2.png"/>
    <span>bla2</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to avoid that extra space between the elements. The user should be able to navigate between items & delete them with a single key press. Also there's a weird behaviour with the cursor (when you delete the empty space, the cursor moves inside the item)

Comment: Can you explain your use case a bit? What kind of elements/content will be allowed in the contenteditable div?

Answer (score 0):

use `display: inline-block;` and `white-space: nowrap;`

Edit:
remove the space between the labels

```css
.keyword-item {
  background-color: #EEFDE5;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: unset;
  cursor: pointer; 
  margin: 0 1rem;
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
}

img {
  padding-left: 2%;
}

span {
  padding-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="expression-textarea"><label class="keyword-item" contenteditable="false">
    <input type="hidden" value="1">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/small/16/000000/download-2.png"/>
        <span>bla</span>
    </label><label class="keyword-item" contenteditable="false">
    <input type="hidden" value="2">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/small/16/000000/download-2.png"/>
        <span>bla bla 2</span>
    </label><label class="keyword-item" contenteditable="false">
        <input type="hidden" value="18">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/small/16/000000/download-2.png"/>
        <span>bla2</span>
     </label>
</div>
```

Comment: That solves the first problem by adding space between the elements,which is not a desired behaviour. It doesn't solve the second problem whatsover.

Comment: @noamyg you need to remove the spaces between the labels. please check the updated snippet

Comment: Now there are huge gaps between the items & lose of focus while navigating with arrow keys